# SSL Personal Certificate link to Intermediate Certificate is broken

Tags: nginx, iis, windows-server-2012, ssl-certificate

Thank You for reading.

I have a test server built where I am trying to implement a encrypt communication using SSL/TLS. The communication is between IIS (web server, where asp.net application is published) and NGINX at the remote server.

I am having problem establishing communication as the IIS sends an empty certificate to NGINX when NGINX sends a certificate request to IIS. The intermediate certificate in the windows server is what the NGINX is expecting.

I have found that there is a broken link between SSL certificate of ASP.NET application and the intermediate certificate.

This is the inhouse dev environment, so the ssl/tls communication should be eastablished using self-assigned certificate only.

[Personal Certificate Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmF4z.png)

Now, when I checked the SSL using online checker, I receive the following snapshot.

[SSL online checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXiiG.png)

I believe that the broken link here may be the reason of the lack of encrypt communication. I am not sure.

Thank You for reading my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chain has no intermediates, so they can't be sent.

Over TLS the End-Entity certificate (either client or server auth, depending on who is sending it) is transmitted, along with any intermediates, but NOT the self-issued root certificate.

Your system will need to have already had the root certificate to determine trust, and your system will need to have already had a way of building chains, so the TLS implementors decided that sending the root certificate is a waste of bytes on the wire.

```
* Root
|
-- * Intermediate 1
   |
   -- * Intermediate 2
      |
      -- * Intermediate 3
         |
         ...
            |
            -- * End-Entity / Leaf
```

Most modern infrastructure is Root -> One Intermedate -> End-Entity.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I missed a step of generating the root and tls certificate chain before generating client pk12.